# Convert digits to bits in RSA

Tags: rsa

I'm reading a book about RSA and I'm in the part "attack by module factorization" and the books says "This method is valid from 10 digits (33 bits) to 90 (297 bits)".

1 digit = 1 byte = 8 bits. Then, 10 should be 80 bits, no?

The second question is, and what attack is valid for < 10 digits?

Comment: No. A digit means a base 10 digit, which is equivalent to about 3.322 bits = log (base 2) of 10. As for the second question, how the heck should we know? You have the book, not us.

Comment: But the book says 33 bits (no 3322)...
And a base 10 digit is decimal, and a number is 8 bits ¿?

Comment: erm...10 times 3.322 is 33.22, not 3322.

Comment: Ah, ok! 33.22 ~= 33. And sorry, but I don't understand "A digit means a base 10 digit, which is equivalent to about 3.322 bits = log (base 2) of 10" --> 10*3=30

Comment: The number of bits and number of digits are always a multiple of each other. Take e.g. 1024 (very near 999). That's 2^10, so 10 digits. I.e. 10 bits digits is about 3 *full* digits. So for a quick approximation you can do digits = (bits * 3) / 10 or bits = (digits / 3) * 10 - and round *up*, as there is no such thing as a partial digit or bit.

Comment: First, you said 2^10, then, 10 digits would be 2, no 3, no? "I.e. 10 bits digits is about 3 full digits"